# Passing reactive to module server function with `updateSelectizeInput`

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinymodules

The goal of this module is to take a reactive input e.g. a dataframe dataset, and updates the `choices` argument in selectize input with the rownames of this reactive input dataframe.

It works fine without modularization, but when I try to implement the module server function, I get this error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
```

Here is my attempt at modularizing the app, that produces the error:

```
select_ui <- function(id, label = 'select input'){
  tagList(
    selectizeInput(inputId = 'select_input',
                   label = 'Select input',
                   choices = NULL,
                   options = list(placeholder = 'Select')
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput('print')
  )
}

select_server <- function(id, choices) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    req(choices())

    output$print <- renderPrint({
      choices()
    })

    observeEvent(choices(), {
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, 'select_input',
        choices = choices(),
        server = T)
    })
  })
}

select_app <- function(...){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    select_ui('select_input')
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    choices <- reactive({
      rownames(datasets::ability.cov$cov)
      })
    select_server('select_input', choices = choices())
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server, ...)
}
```

The unmodularized, working app, that functions as intended:

```
# not modularized version:
select_app2 <- function(...){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(inputId = 'select_input',
                   label = 'Select input',
                   choices = NULL,
                   options = list(placeholder = 'Select')
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput('print')
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    choices <- reactive({
      rownames(datasets::ability.cov$cov)
    })

    output$print <- renderPrint({
      cat('here are the choices: ', choices())
    })

    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, 'select_input',
        choices = choices(),
        server = T)
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server, ...)
}
```

I think it has something to do with passing the reactive `choices` to my module server function, and also with the `update*` function.

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: You have `req(choices())` outside a reactive context, that is the error (or one of the errors).

Comment: Thanks,
I took out `req(choices())` and this the new error:

`Warning: Error in choices: could not find function "choices"`

Comment: Because you do `select_server('select_input', choices = choices())` instead of `select_server('select_input', choices = choices)`.

Comment: Thank you!! I think I misunderstand something fundamentally about reactives. Why is the proper syntax using without `()` of passing a reactive object to a module server function?

Comment: `()` is for when you want to get at the contents of the reactive, but when you pass into the  module definition, you dont want that, you want the reactive, not the reactive contents; within the module you access the contents  `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `req(choices())` outside a reactive context, that is the error (or one of the errors).

Because you do `select_server('select_input', choices = choices())` instead of `select_server('select_input', choices = choices)`. –Stephane Laurent